# How to change active tab url in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm discovering how to develop a Chrome extension and I can't find actually how to change the active url. I would like to get informations from websites and pack them.

Actually the first lines of this code work. I've tried different ways to change the url, can't find the right one...

```
$("body").css('background-color', 'pink');
$("body").html('COUCOU');
setTimeout(function(){ 
      var myNewUrl = "http://www.google.com";
      chrome.tabs.update(active, {url: myNewUrl});
}, 2000);;
```

My manifest is :

```
{
  "name": "A browser action with a popup that changes the page color",
  "description": "Change the current page color",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab", "tabs"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
   "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.js", "background.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
  }],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Of note: don't create code _snippets_ if the code can't be actually run as an example. Just format sections as code, there's an option in the editor to do so.

Comment: Ty, the code part was bugged

Answer (score 2):

Let's see the signature of the `tabs.update` method [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update):

> ```
> chrome.tabs.update(integer tabId, object updateProperties, function callback)
> ```
>
> integer   (optional) `tabId`
> Defaults to the selected tab of the current window.
>
> object    `updateProperties`
> [...]

Since you want the current (selected) tab, you can just *omit* the tabId - it's marked as *optional.*

```
chrome.tabs.update({url: myNewUrl});
```

---

From a content script, the situation is different. You [don't have access to `chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#capabilities).

But you can simply change the `document`'s properties, as you're in the context of the active page already:

```
document.location = myNewUrl;
```

Comment: Now it says : background.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined. I don't understand....

Comment: Apologies, I missed the part it's a content script (which you should _never ever_ call `background.js` since it's confusing).

Comment: I renamed it, it doesn't change anything. It still says to me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined. I don't understand....

Comment: You have to 1) reload the extension from `chrome://extensions` for changes to apply, 2) reload the target page for the content script to load.

Comment: That's what I did. I'm wondering if I can call the function just like this. SHould'nt I go through chrome.runtime or chrome.query?

Comment: If you really changed your code (so it does not have `chrome.tabs.update` anymore, which you can't use), and reloaded properly, this error should not appear.

Comment: With document.location, it works perfectly. But it refresh the "newUrl" every 2 seconds. Do you know why? Shouldn't it be just 1 time?

Comment: After navigation, content script is injected again, no matter how you navigated there. You need some extra logic if you don't want it to happen every time or on every page..

Comment: I don't understand why this code is re-injected... Do you have some documentations about it?

Comment: That's not really appropriate to discuss it in the comment thread; it no longer is relevant to this question. I would recommend reading the [content script docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and making a new question if you still need help.